# Changing div background upon user image selection

Tags: javascript

I have div, thumbwrap1, which changes color when an image is selected but what I am confused about is how to remove the background of the current selected div when the user selects another image?

```
       <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function doOnChannelLoad(e) {   

    if (e.mediaList && e.mediaList.length > 0) {

      var playlistHTML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < e.mediaList.length; i++) {
        var media = e.mediaList[i];
        if (media) {
          playlistHTML += '<div id="thumbwrap">';
          playlistHTML += '<div id="thumbwrap1"  onClick="javascript:myFunction(this);">';
          playlistHTML += '<a href="javascript:onPlaylistItemClick(\'' + media.id + '\');">';
          playlistHTML += '<img width="105"  border "1" src="' + media.thumbnailUrl + '"/ >';
           playlistHTML += '</div>';
          playlistHTML += '<div id="thumbwrap-title">' + media.title + '</div>';
          playlistHTML += '</a>';
          playlistHTML += '</div>';
        }
      }

      playlistHTML += '<br style="clear:both;" />';

      var playlistBox = document.getElementById('playlist-box').innerHTML = playlistHTML;
      drawBorder(e.id);

    }

  }

  function onPlaylistItemClick(mediaId) {

    DelvePlayer.doSetMedia(mediaId, false);

  }

  function onChannelListClick(channelId) {

    DelvePlayer.doLoadChannel(channelId);

  }  

  function drawBorder(elementId) {

    $('li').removeClass('channelSelected');
    document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("class", "channelSelected");

  }
```

function myFunction(divObj) {

```
divObj.style.background="#E79F2C";
 $(this).remove(divObj);
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: The generated HTML from the JavaScript is invalid. You are creating multiple `DIV` with same `ID` as `thumbwrap`. First rectify the same.

Comment: If you need to style a number of elements identically, you should be using the class attribute, rather than the id attribute. If you also used a class of (say) 'active', you could simply apply that class to the most recently clicked element, while clearing it from the others. The for-loop will generate multiple elements with the same id: `thumbwrap`, `thumbwrap1` and `thumbwrap-title`. More than 1 element with any given id results in invalid html.

Comment: The thumbwrap1 changes background color around the image,from white to orange, when the user click on it.  This is what I want, but when I click on another image then, I want the orange background of the previously selected image to change back to no background and the newly selected image to be orange.

I am not entirely certain what you mean.  Do you know of a site for reference with code examples?  Thanks.

Comment: @DawnAbbot - Thanks for the explanation. That's more or less what I thought it did, and the purpose of the markup was(is). Here's a quick and dirty example of what I mean. The divs are added dynamically, just right-click one of them and choose "Inspect Element" - you can see that each div has the class "square" the last one to be clicked _also_ has the class "active". I simply get the list of elements that posses the class "active". I remove the active class from any tiles that posses it, then toggle the "active" class for the div that was clicked on. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/b92Gx/

Comment: Thank you for your example link.

Comment: You're welcome. (Pssst - if you type @username at the start of a comment, the specified user will get a _red_ notification of the response. E.g <at>DawnAbbot or <at>enhzflep. - substitute @ for <at>. I just refreshed this page a couple of times to check for a response. :) )

Comment: @enhzflep - I integrated you code into mine.  The only thing is that when I click on the thumbnail is changes color and then changes back again right away.  http://jsfiddle.net/rabbott/b92Gx/12/

Comment: Just had a look at the jsfiddle link Dawn, I see a couple of issues. The first - I don't see anything other than the text "Playlist Example 3", "NOW PLAYING:", "SELECT A CHANNEL", "Music Channel" and "Tutorial Channel". The next issue I see is that while I used an *arbitrarily* named class, "active", you have used a css-pseudo class "active" I.e look at line 103 of the css - you've used .thumbwrap:active (the :active is a pseudo-class, that has special meaning, just like :hover does) I'll have a bit more of a look, but currently I can't see anything to click or behaviour to observe. :)

Comment: Okay, a couple of issues found. (1) mInit() is failing. There are no divs with the className of "thumbwrap" on the page immediately after the page has loaded. (2) You haven't assigned anything to the `DelvePlayer` variable. (3) You haven't attached delvePlayerCallback to anything - the function is never called. Perhaps it should be specified in one of the params for the swf? (4) The DrawBorder() function uses $('li') - this looks like jQuery, yet I don't see it's inclusion anywhere. (The swf showed-up once I copied the jsfiddle code and saved it locally)

Comment: @enhzflep-I tried to use playbox-list instead of thumbwrap and that did not work either.